# Convert to lowercase and concatenate

Tags: php, concatenation, lowercase

What is the best to convert to lowercase and concatenate?

```
$first      = "Abc Def";
$second= "Ghi Jkl";
$result= $first.$second;
```

**Expected output:** `abcdef.ghijkl`

Comment: `strtolower(str_replace(" ","",$result))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this simplest one can be helpful too. Here we using multiple functions `implode`, `str_replace` and `strtolower`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/806521)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$first = "Abc Def";
$second = "Ghi Jkl";

echo strtolower(str_replace(" ","",implode(".", array($first,$second))));
```

**Output:**
`abcdef.ghijkl`

Answer (score 1):

`strtolower` to convert to lowercase

```
$first = str_replace(' ','',strtolower("Abc Def"));
$second= str_replace(' ','',strtolower("Ghi Jkl"));
$result= $first.$second;
```

Comment: In Expected answer there is no space and there is `.` too between them.

Comment: sorry bro, @SahilGulati havent seen that, thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtolower` to convert lowercase and `str_replace` to remove space.
Finally join the two variables and add a `'.'` between them.

```
$first      = "Abc Def";
$second= "Ghi Jkl";

$low_first = strtolower(str_replace(" ","",$first));
$low_second = strtolower(str_replace(" ","",$second));
echo $finalresult = $low_first.'.'.$low_second;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
abcdef.ghijkl
```